# Can I pass a list of strings into a python function?

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a function that takes in a list of strings and prints the first letter of each string. I defined the function as `firstLetter(lst)`. and defined the list as `lst = ["one", "two", "longer statement"]`. However, the function doesn't seem to be reading the list as the function returns nothing. I'll leave the code I used in the relevant section. Thanks for your help.

```
lst = ["one", "two", "longer statement"]

def firstLetter(lst):
    for item in lst:
        print(item[0])
```

I tested the loop inside the function, it seems to work on its own, but I can't seem to feed the list through the function. I am expecting to see:

```
0
t
l
```

However, the function returns nothing.

Comment: you have to call your function. you are not calling the function. declaring it is not sufficient

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of "What's the purpose of the return statement". The problem with the function is not the lack of a return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function.

```
lst = ["one", "two", "longer statement"]

def firstLetter(lst):
 for item in lst:
  print(item[0])


firstLetter(lst)
```